WP Rest API to upload image with URL : Operation timed out after XXXX milliseconds with 0 bytes received
I want to upload pictures to the gallery of my WordPress via REST API. I use this function :
function upload_image_to_woocommerce($image_path)
{

    global $url;
    global $apiCredential;

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($apiCredential),
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($image_path) . '"',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_path);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $image_data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch))
    {
        throw new Exception("Error " . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

}

Sometimes it works, but sometimes I got the error : Operation timed out after XXXX milliseconds with 0 bytes received
Do I use the right way to upload my pictures? Or my host has some issues? I tried with different wordpress, on different host, and the issue is still there :(
Thanks
